# Is Windows really so broken regarding credentails?

Tags: login, windows-os

I'm wondering if I missed something huge or has Windows really such a bad UX that you need to type in your credentials everywhere without any (half) automated autofill options?

I'm using an password manager of cause, but I'm curious if I missed something or is there really no way that an App(lication) can ask for credentials from a password manager or anything like autofill.

How should Windows or Desktop applications manage logins today out of the vision of Microsoft (if there is any)?

Bonus question: Is there also no way to sync settings like credentials in Windows without 3rd party tools?

Answer (score 2):

If you, the user, are experiencing friction in a place where you're expecting there to be no friction then, indeed, there is room for improvement for the UX.

The "why is this" part is impossible to assess from the outside. Generally though: products are developed with certain constraints. A designer may come up with the perfect UX, only for a developer to come back and say "actually we can't do that", or for someone from the legal team to come back to say "you must change that".

Having to sign into the *Clock* app separately is somewhat ridiculous of course, and not having the comfort of the browser's password manager in this case isn't helpful either. However, there may be some serious anti-trust concerns and/or privacy concerns combined with that which prevent this. [Microsoft already is in a position where its approach of included software is subject to new regulation](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2023/11/16/previewing-changes-in-windows-to-comply-with-the-digital-markets-act-in-the-european-economic-area/).

It of course also has 500 other possible reasons - maybe the layoffs affected things, maybe there's general incompetency afoot, maybe it will get updated tomorrow, maybe it's something else still.

> Bonus question: Is there also no way to sync settings like credentials in Windows without 3rd party tools?

There is, Windows 11 can sync OneDrive folders, apps installed from the Microsoft store, and preferences such as passwords and language.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/about-windows-backup-and-sync-settings-deebcba2-5bc0-4e63-279a-329926955708#WindowsVersion=Windows_11

Comment: Very interesting (both links) I missed that _"Remember my apps"_ part, which seems to be limited to Microsoft Store Apps. Do you know more about this? Otherwise I will search it myself :-)

Comment: The limitation to the MS store may be because Windows knows how to install these apps and where their settings are. For normal exe/msi installers, those things in principle can install things anywhere and have their settings in documents, appdata/roaming or local, or somewhere else entirely.

Comment: All things which can be managed, but that is of cause not in our hands. Do you know any documentation regarding that option to save the settings? Is that limited to UWP? I just found out that the registration takes 14€ for personal accounts.